# Screenshot of active window

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, screenshot

In former versions of Xubuntu, I was able to take a screenshot using Alt+PrintScreen. This doesn't work anymore in 12.04. Have the key binding changed?

Comment: I had <Alt> + Print in my keyboard settings for launching `xfce4-screenshooter -w`. I just reset the keybinding to <Alt> + <Print> which is recognized as `Sys_req`. And now everything is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are running xfce, there is an entry in the FAQ:

*"My desktop is so nice, I want to make a screenshot! How can I do that in Xfce?"*

The answer mention **xfce4-screenshooter** http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/xfce4-screenshooter (it can capture an active window too)

Answer (score 7):

I have solved the same problem in Xubuntu 13.04 in the following way:

1. Open **Settings Manager -> Keyboard**.
2. Choose **Application Shortcuts** tab.
3. Select **xfce4-screenshooter -w** command and change the shortcut to <kbd>Sys_Req</kbd> (Press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> button first and then any <kbd>Alt</kbd> button).

Answer (score 3):

It appears that <kbd>Alt+Print</kbd> conflicts with another keybinding in recent versions of Ubuntu.  I was able to work around it by setting the keybinding to <kbd>Shift+Print</kbd>.

Also see this answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/258735/ubuntu-10-10-screenshot-of-active-window-doesnt-work